# Proximal Operator of a Quadratic Function

Tags: matrices, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, approximation, proximal-operators

What is a proximal operator and how would one derive it in general for a function?

In particular, if I had a function: $ f(x) = x^TQx + b^Tx + c $ How would I get the proximal operator for this if Q was a m dimensional square symmetric positive semidefinite matrix?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proximal operator is the map $\def\prox{\mathop{\rm prox}\nolimits}\prox_f \colon \mathbb R^m \to \mathbb R^m$ given by 
$$ \prox_f(x) = {\rm argmin}_{y \in \mathbb R^m} f(y) + \frac 12\|x-y\|^2 $$
For the given $f$ and $x,y \in \mathbb R^m$, we have 
\begin{align*}
 g_x(y) &:= f(y) + \frac 12\|x-y\|^2\\ &= y^tQy + b^ty + c + \frac 12x^tx + x^ty + \frac 12y^ty\\
    &= y^t\left(Q + \frac 12\right)y + (b+x)^ty  + c + \frac 12x^tx
\end{align*}
Now $Q + \frac 12$ is symmetric and positive definite, hence this has a unique minimum. To find it, we compute $g_x$'s critical point, we have for $h \in \mathbb R^m$:
\begin{align*}
  g_x'(y)h &= 2y^t\left(Q + \frac 12\right)h + (b+x)^t h 
\end{align*}
so $g_x'(y) = 0$ iff 
$$ y = \left(2Q + 1\right)^{-1}(b+x) $$
That is 
$$ \prox_f(x) = \left(2Q + 1\right)^{-1}(b+x) $$

Comment: Thanks martini. Could you possibly also help me with http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/525955/proximal-functions ?  I am stuck with the proximal function derivation.