# Proximal Functions / Proximal Operators

Tags: convex-analysis, approximation, game-theory, proximal-operators

I am a little bit new to proximal functions and I am currently stuck with the following problems

How would I derive the prox function for the regularizer (h(x) function) : $\alpha\sum_{k+} $ and for $ \alpha ||z||_2$?

Any hint about how to start and do this would be great.

Comment: What are $\sum_{k+}$ and $z$?

Comment: I edited it. Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice table of proximal operators of several commonly used functions in [Combettes and Pesquet, 2010](http://arxiv.org/abs/0912.3522/). You might want to have a look.

Comment: Please try to describe as much here as possible in order to make the answer self-contained. Links are fine as support, but they can go stale and then an answer which is nothing more than a link loses its value.

Comment: Oups! Sorry. Will do that.